# Simulating an Oracle sequence with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Our domain model deals with sales invoices, each of which has a unique, automatically generated number. When creating an invoice, our SalesInvoiceService retrieves a number from a SalesInvoiceNumberGenerator, creates a SalesInvoice using this number and a few other objects (seller, buyer, issue date, etc.) and stores it through the SalesInvoiceRepository. Since we are using MongoDB as our database, our MongoDbSalesInvoiceNumberGenerator uses a findAndModify command with $inc 1 on a given InvoicePolicies.nextSalesInvoiceNumber to generate this unique number, similar to what we would using an Oracle sequence.

This is working in normal situations. However, when invoice creation fails because of a broken business rule (e.g. invalid issue date), an exception is thrown and our InvoicePolicies.nextSalesInvoiceNumber has alreay been incremented. Obviously, since there is no transaction managing this unit of work, this increment is not rolled back, so we end up with lost invoice numbers. We do offer a manual compensation mechanism to the user, but we would like to avoid this sort of situation in the first place.

How would you deal with this situation? And no, switching to another database is not option :)

Thanks!

Comment: Simulating transactions on mongodb is futile. Best you can do is piles of fragile application logic, which are hard to understand and maintain. IMHO.

Comment: Mongodb doesn't have transactions not because devs didn't like them or something. It's because transactions are extremely hard to do right.

Comment: An alternative solution is to tolerate missing invoice numbers. :)

Comment: FWIW, in Oracle, in case of rollback, the sequence numbers are *not* pulled back. As a consequence, Oracle cannot guarantee there is no hole in a sequence ... just like in your MongoDB implementation. The quest of a "no hole" sequence numbering tolerant to fault/rollback seems an utopia: for example, how would that behave if per some regulation you need to *remove* a past invoice ? Will you renumber all the following invoice just to enforce that consecutive numbering ?

Comment: Yet another alternative solution is to set invoice number only after successful save. That is, you insert all invoice data sans the number. If the write succeeds, you retrieve number from the sequence and issue an update to that invoice.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Sylvain You're right I forgot about that, haven't worked with Oracle in a couple of years now :) Sergio I was toying with the idea of setting the number after the invoice was saved following a domain event, maybe eventually we'll do that. For the moment, I think we'll tolerate the gaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: What you want is [strict serializability](http://www.bailis.org/blog/linearizability-versus-serializability/), but you probably won't get it, unless you give up concurrency completely (then you even get linearizability, theoretically). Gap-free is easy, but making sure that today's invoice doesn't get a lower number than yesterdays is practically impossible.

This is tricky, or at least, very expensive. That is also true for any other data store, because you'll have to limit the concurrency of the application to *guarantee* it. Think of an auto-increasing stamp that is passed around in an office, but some office workers lose letters. Tricky... But you can reduce the likelihood.

Generating sequences without gaps is hard when contention is high, and very hard in a distributed system. Keeping a lock for the entire time the invoice is generated is usually not an option, though that would be easy. So let's try that:

> Easiest way out: Use a **singleton background worker**, i.e. a single-threaded process that runs on a single machine. Have it explicitly check whether the current number is really present in the invoice collection. Because it's single-threaded on a single machine, it can't have race conditions. *Done*, via limiting concurrency.

When allowing concurrency, things get messy:

It might be best to use something like a [two-phase commit protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol). Essentially, make the entire invoice creation process a long-running transaction, and store the pending transactions explicitly, i.e. store all numbers that *haven't* been used yet, but reserved.

Then track the completion status of each and every transaction. If a transaction hasn't finished after some timeout, consider that number available again. It's hard enough to add that to the counter code, but it's possible (check if a timed out transaction is present, otherwise get a new counter value).

There are several possible errors, but they can all be resolved. This is better explained in the link and on the net. Generally, getting the implementation right is hard though.

The timeout poses a problem, however, because you need to hard-code an assumption about the time it takes for invoices to be generated. That can be awkward close to day/month/year barriers, since you'll want to avoid creating invoice 12345 in 2015 and 12344 in 2014.

Even this won't guarantee gap free numbers for limited time intervals: if no more request is made that could use the gap number in the current year, you're facing a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive and clear answer, very enlightening. I hadn't realized it would be that complicated. I guess we'll have to tolerate the invoice number gaps :)

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if using something like `findAndModify` and the new [Transactions API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486169/simulating-an-oracle-sequence-with-mongodb) combined could be used to achieve something like that while also accounting for gaps if ran within a transaction then? I haven't personally tried it, and my project isn't far along yet to worry about the billing system but would love to be able to use the same database for everything to make things a bit easier to operate.

One problem I would think is probably a write bottleneck but this should only take a few milliseconds I'd imagine and you could probably use a different counter for every jurisdiction or store like real life stores do. Then the cash register number could be part of it too, which I guess guess cash register numbers in the digital world could be the transaction processing server it went to if say you used microservices for example, so you could load balance round robin between them probably. That's assuming if it's uses a per document lock - which from my understanding it does possibly.

The only main time I'd probably worry about this bottleneck is if you had a very popular store or around black Friday where there's a huge spike or doing recurring invoices.

Comment: That's probably the better and more straightforward way today. The hard part then only is to make sure that the transaction itself is correct (i.e. all validations can be run inside the transaction and a document is created that contains everything required for the invoice to be correct and complete), but that is a lot easier and much more of a business problem. Since a number of jurisdictions have tightened their rules in the past years (e.g., iirc, Poland and Italy), doing this right might have become a lot more relevant.